# What is wrong with my iptables rules that is resulting in SSH connection disconnecting?

Tags: iptables

I am trying to setup the iptable rules on my VPS so that it whitelists my IP address and drops all packets from all other IP addresses. However, when I tried this I lost my SSH connection.

I tries to do this by writing two ACCEPT rules which for my IP address. Then changing the INPUT, OUTPUT, and FORWARD chains to drop all connections.

```
root@user:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
root@user:~# iptables -A INPUT -s [my_ip] -j ACCEPT
root@user:~# iptables -A OUTPUT -s [my_ip] -j ACCEPT
root@user:~# iptables -P FORWARD DROP
root@user:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  [my_ip]              anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  [my_ip]              anywhere
root@user:~# iptables -P INPUT DROP
root@user:~# iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
Connection reset by [VPS_ip] port 22
PS C:\Users\user_2> ssh root@[VPS_ip]
ssh: connect to host [VPS_ip] port 22: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
root@user:~# iptables -A OUTPUT -s [my_ip] -j ACCEPT
```

should have been:

```
root@user:~# iptables -A OUTPUT -d [my_ip] -j ACCEPT
```